# Highcharts donut chart customization

Tags: highcharts, javascript, donut-chart

I have a license for highcharts and I would like to create a char like the one bellow:

[image]

The most similar component on highcharts is the following one:

[image]

Does someone know is is posible to replace the PIE inside for just a percent? or some other good client side javascript librarie to do it?

You can find a demo and the API in the following links.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-donut/

API http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check about `innerSize`.
`"The size of the inner diameter for the pie. A size greater than 0 renders a donut chart. Can be a percentage or pixel value. Percentages are relative to the size of the plot area. Pixel values are given as integers. Defaults to 0."` [reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.innerSize)

Than you can take a look this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/e2qpa/3/) which shows how to put the `text` inside the donut chart.

Hope it help you.

Comment: Check out this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/e2qpa/47/. This is using the example you listed. So many possibilities with this. The only "flaw" I see is in aligning the background gray circle and text. Seems the center is not really where you think it should be when looking at the final donut chart.

Answer (score 3):

You might try using **title** as an alternative and rather simple approach.

```
            title: {
                text: 'Budget',
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '9.5px'
                } 
            },
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amigoo/zwod86e1/

Answer (score 0):

```
 function(chart4) {
chart4.renderer.text('<span style="word-wrap: break-word !important;">Reduced by <br/>10 Years</span>', (chart4.chartWidth/2)-38, (chart4.chartHeight/2)-5)
             .css({

                color: '#4b4b4b',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '12px'

            })
            .add();
}
```