# How to make highcharts bubble chart bubble looks like donut symbol instead of full round circle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I have a basic highcharts bubble chart. With all bubbles as rounded cirlce. I want to make it looks like a donut symbol. How can I do that in Highcharts ?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bubble/

Code

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts Bubbles'
        },

        series: [{
            data: [[97, 36, 79], [94, 74, 60], [68, 76, 58], [64, 87, 56], [68, 27, 73], [74, 99, 42], [7, 93, 87], [51, 69, 40], [38, 23, 33], [57, 86, 31]]
        }, {
            data: [[25, 10, 87], [2, 75, 59], [11, 54, 8], [86, 55, 93], [5, 3, 58], [90, 63, 44], [91, 33, 17], [97, 3, 56], [15, 67, 48], [54, 25, 81]]
        }, {
            data: [[47, 47, 21], [20, 12, 4], [6, 76, 91], [38, 30, 60], [57, 98, 64], [61, 17, 80], [83, 60, 13], [67, 78, 75], [64, 12, 10], [30, 77, 82]]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: you are trying to do a donut chart for  each series?  see if this helps [highcharts-donut-chart-customization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219286/highcharts-donut-chart-customization)

Comment: no I want to style the bubble so it looks like a donut (small hole in the center)

Comment: You can define each bubble as extra pie serie. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zh8t2cev/. Second solution is prepare your own custom marker, by add new symbol. Similiar symbols: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499558/set-custom-legend-item-symbol-or-icon-in-highcharts