# How to create grouped piechart

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2

I have this pandas dataframe:

```
df =

GROUP   MARK
ABC     1
ABC     0
ABC     1
DEF     1
DEF     1
DEF     1
DEF     1
XXX     0
```

I need to create a piechart (using Python or R). The size of each pie should correspond to the proportional count (i.e. the percent) of rows with particular `GROUP`. Moreover, each pie should be divided into 2 sub-parts corresponding to the percent of rows with `MARK==1` and `MARK==0` within given `GROUP`.

I was googling for this type of piecharts and found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019879/hierarchic-pie-donut-chart-from-pandas-dataframe-using-bokeh-or-matplotlib). But this example seems to be overcomplicated for my case. Another good example is done in [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219286/highcharts-donut-chart-customization), which doesn't serve for me because of the language.

Can somebody tell me what's the name of this type of piecharts and where can I find some examples of code in Python or R.

Comment: You can use the `highcharter` which is an R wrapper for the highcharts JS library (used by your 2nd "good example"). I don't think this is a great way to present the data though.

Comment: @arvi1000: Can you post some example of pie chart? I can only find bar plots and timeseries.

Comment: While you could use a pie, I don't think that this is the best way to represent hierarchical data. There are a lot of alternatives such as a treemap or a waffle plot.  If you want to stick with radial options, I'd look at a coxcomb plot or a sunburst plot.  All of these options have packages to facilitate plotting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in R that uses base R only. Not sure how you want to arrange your pies, but I used `par(mfrow=...)`.

```
df <- read.table(text="  GROUP   MARK
ABC     1
ABC     0
ABC     1
DEF     1
DEF     1
DEF     1
DEF     1
XXX     0", header=TRUE)

plot_pie <- function(x, multiplier=1, label){
   pie(table(x), radius=multiplier * length(x), main=label)
}

par(mfrow=c(1,3), mar=c(0,0,2,0))
invisible(lapply(split(df, df$GROUP), function(x){
  plot_pie(x$MARK, label=unique(x$GROUP),
       multiplier=0.2)
}))
```

This is the result:

[image: threepies]